# how to auto export .class file with when exported .java file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I'm using eclipse and i need to export `.java` file with his related `.class` at same time , please not I'm already can export `.java` file but I don't know how to export his related `.class` file .

I exported in the below way  :

[image]

Comment: You normally do this by Exporting a JAR and checking the option to include the source files as well as the class files - "File > Export" and select "Java > JAR file"

Comment: The corresponding `.class` file(s) are located in the output folder (`bin`, `target/classes` or ...) in the to the source folder corresponding subfolder.

Comment: @greg-449 i don't wanna exported by jar , i want check `.java` file auto check `.class` file

Comment: @howlger , thank you i know that but i don't want need this we are deploy to production in hard way.  so i need the above way to make our work easy .

Comment: The export dialog you use is not Java specific and shows also checkboxes for the `.class` files (inside the output folder, not inside the source folder). When you deploy only some classes, this can cause issues since constants might be inlined.

Comment: @howlger , can you please explain more cos i'm not familiar with eclipse .

Comment: `MSDCTSConnectorActions.java` is in `<source folder>/es/cls/ctsc/` (shown in the screenshot) and `MSDCTSConnectorActions.class` is in `<output folder>/es/cls/ctsc/` (scroll for it).